# I have some (basic) postfix misconfiguration, cannot fing out where

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, email, postfix

it's the first time i use postfix and i'm having some problem configuring it. It does send mail to the "real" out world, but i'm not capable to recive mail sended from the web.
I think there's an hosts misconfiguration with host, i've tried some solution but none had effects

The server is running Debain Stable (Lenny)

**cat /etc/hostname**

```
hosting
```

**cat /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
94.23.70.214    artkiller-web.com hosting mail
```

**cat /etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
myorigin = $mydomain
myhostname = mail.artkiller-web.com
mydomain = artkiller-web.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, /etc/postfix/local-domain
mynetworks_style = host
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

**cat /etc/postfix/local-domain**

```
artkiller-web.com
www.artkiller-web.com
```

**cat /etc/postfix/local-domain**

```
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
info: artkiller
root: artkiller
```

I'm not sure, maybe it could be a DNS configuration problem. This are the relevant DNS record:

```
MX         artkiller-web.com.          10 mail.artkiller-web.com.   
A          artkiller-web.com.          94.23.70.214     
CNAME      www.artkiller-web.com.      artkiller-web.com.   
A          mail.artkiller.web.com.  94.23.70.214
```

Hope i give you any useful information - thanks for help

Alessandro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `A` record for mail.artkiller-web.com is missing.

Comment: You are right: Host mail.artkiller-web.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: You're right - a misconfigurated the A record for mail.artkiller-web, i've just modified it to match "mail.artkiller-web.com." and i'll wait for propagate. If it'll work i'll mark the question as answered